# Adjusting the y-axis in ggplot (bar size, ordering, formatting)

Tags: ggplot2

I have the following **data.table**:

[image: Text]

I would like to have a plot which shows the columns **symbol** and **value** in a **box plot**. The boxes should be ordered by the column **value**.

My code, that I've tried:

```
plot1 <- ggplot(symbols, aes(symbol, value, fill = from)) +
  geom_bar(stat = 'identity') +
  ggtitle(paste0("Total quantity traded: ", format(sum(symbols$quantity), scientific = FALSE, nsmall = 2, big.mark = " "))) +
  theme_bw()
plot1
```

This returns the following plot:
[image: Text]

What I would like to change:
- flip x- and y-axis
- show the correct height of boxes (y-axis)...currently the relation between the boxes is not correct.
- decreasing order of the boxes by columns **value**
- format the y-axis with two digits
- make the x-axis readable...currently the x-axis is just a long bunch of what is written in column **symbol**.

Thanks upfront for the help!

Comment: It usually easier to get help if you provide a reproducible example that includes data. The data doesn't have to be real but can be random. I am afraid that a screenshot of the data is not enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make things a bit easier, it is suggested that you post your data frame as the output of `dput(your.data.frame)`, which presents code that can be used to replicate your dataset in `r`.

With that being said, I recreated your data (it was not too big)--some numbers were rounded a bit to make things easier.

A few comments:

- **y-axis numbers are odd:** The numbers on your y-axis are not numeric.  If you type `str(your.data.frame)` you'll probably notice that "value" is not numeric, but a character or factor.  This can be easily remedied via: `df$value <- as.numeric(df$value)`, where `df` is your dataframe.
- **flipping axis:**  You can use `coord_flip()` (typically added to the end of your `ggplot` call.  Be warned that when you do this, your aesthetics flip for the plot, so just keep that in mind.
- **your dataframe name is also a function/data name in r:**  This may not be causing any issues (due to your environment), but just be aware to use caution to name your dataset to not have names that are used in `r` elsewhere.  This goes for column/variable names too.  I don't think it causes any issues here, but just an FYI
- **geom_col vs geom_bar:** Check out [this documentation link](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/geom_bar.html) for some description on the differences between `geom_bar` and `geom_col`.  Basically, you want to use `geom_bar` when your y-axis is count, and `geom_col` when your y-axis is a value.  Here, you want to plot a value, so choose `geom_col()`, and not `geom_bar()`.

**Fixing the issues in plot**

Here's the representation of your data (note I rounded... hopefully got the actual data correct, because I manually had to copy each value):

```
   from  symbol  quantity      usd    value
1   BTC BTCUSDT 12910.470 6776.340 87485737
2   ETH ETHUSDT  6168.730  154.398   952445
3   BNB BNBUSDT 51002.650   14.764   753017
4   BNB  BNBBTC 31071.280   14.764   458745
5   ETH  ETHBTC  2216.576  154.398   342236
6   LTC LTCUSDT  4332.024   40.481   175368
7   BNB  BNBETH  3150.030   14.764    46507
8   LTC  LTCBTC   922.560   40.481    37346
9   LTC  LTCBNB   521.476   40.481    21110
10  NEO NEOUSDT  2438.353    7.203    17564
11  NEO  NEOBTC   417.930    7.203     3010
```

Here's the basic plot, flipped:

```
ggplot(df, aes(symbol, value, fill=from)) +
    geom_col() +
    coord_flip()
```

[image]

The problem here is that when you plot values... BTCUSDT is huge in comparison.  I would suggest you plot on *log* of value.  See [this link](https://www.datanovia.com/en/blog/ggplot-log-scale-transformation/) for some advice on how to do that.  I like the `scale_y_log10()` function, since it just works here pretty well:

```
ggplot(df, aes(symbol, value, fill=from)) +
    geom_col() +
    scale_y_log10() +
    coord_flip()
```

[image]

If you wanted to keep the columns going in the vertical orientation, you can still do that and avoid having the text run into each other on the x-axis.  In that case, you can rotate the labels via `theme(axis.text.x=...)`.  Note the adjustments to horizontal and vertical alignment (`hjust=1`), which forces the labels to be "right-aligned":

```
ggplot(df, aes(symbol, value, fill=from)) +
    geom_col() +
    scale_y_log10() +
    theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle=45, hjust=1))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this really valuable solution. I am still impressed of how nice stack overflow helps. :) have a great day.